# How to solve a equation of the form (A'A - yBB')x = 0 with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Using numpy if I had a system of equations:

```
3x + 2y = 5
1x + 4y = 10
```

I could solve them with `numpy.linalg.solve`:

```
a = [[3,2],[1,4]]
b = [5,10]
solution = numpy.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

Now, what if I had two matrices, A and B each of shape (100,100) and I wanted to solve an equation of the form: (A'*A - y*BB')x = 0

I'm unsure as to how I would set this up using `numpy.linalg.solve`

Comment: Presumably `x` must be a vector with length 100, and `y` is scalar.  Is that correct?  Or is `x` also a scalar, as supposed in valentin's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to solve the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem), with `y` being the unknown generalized eigenvalue λ and `x` being the corresponding generalized eigenvector. If that is what you want, you can use [`scipy.linalg.eig`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html).  Here's an example.

To keep the output readable, I'll use arrays with shape (2, 2).

```
In [91]: from scipy.linalg import eig

In [92]: A
Out[92]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [1, 1]])

In [93]: B
Out[93]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 0]])
```

These are the matrices in the equation.

```
In [94]: a = A.T.dot(A)

In [95]: b = B.dot(B.T)
```

Solve the generalized eigenvalue problem:

```
In [96]: lam, v = eig(a, b)
```

These are the generalized eigenvalues (your `y`):

```
In [97]: lam
Out[97]: array([ 6.09287487+0.j,  0.01823624+0.j])
```

The columns of `v` are the generalized eigenvectors (your `x`):

```
In [98]: v
Out[98]: 
array([[ 0.98803087, -0.81473616],
       [ 0.1542563 ,  0.57983187]])
```

Verify the solution.  Note that the results are on the order of 1e-16, i.e. numerically close to 0.

```
In [99]: (a - lam[0]*b).dot(v[:,0])
Out[99]: array([  2.22044605e-16+0.j,  -8.88178420e-16+0.j])

In [100]: (a - lam[1]*b).dot(v[:,1])
Out[100]: array([ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j])
```

Answer (score 1):

This specific equation has an analytical solution:

1. either `x` is 0 and `y` can be anything

either

2. `x` can be anything and then `A'A - yBB' = 0` which **can** be linear and solved using `numpy.linalg.solve`

**can** be linear because the dimensions does not add well

Comment: could you possibly help clarify something for me? the paper I'm reading states that the equation can be solved by the SVD of A and B. Would that then just be `np.linalg.svd(A)` and `np.linalg.svd(B)`, and I just take `s` ?

Comment: maybe this link give you an insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711920/what-is-benefit-to-use-svd-for-solving-ax-b

Comment: If `x` is assumed to be a scalar, then this is fine.  However, the equation looks like the generalized eigenvalue problem, where `x` is a vector.